# vuejs hotel date picker @check-in-changed cannot send value

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

i have been trying to send @check-in-changed and  @check-out-changed values to modal title and when i console log getStartDate method i get correct date but when i send it to modal title i get value of undefined. Can you please help?

hotel-date-picker:

```
<HotelDatePicker :gridStyle="false" :showSingleMonth="true" :minNights="7" :alwaysVisible="true"
                                   :showPrice="true" priceSymbol='€' :periodDates="detail.periodDates"
                                   :disabledDates="detail.disabledDates" @check-in-changed="getStartDate"
                                   @check-out-changed="getEndDate">
                  </HotelDatePicker>
```

methods:

```
 getStartDate(newDate) {
      console.log(newDate)
      return (newDate)
    },

    getEndDate(newDate){
      return (newDate)
    },
```

console.log of getStartDate:

```
Date Mon Nov 22 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)
```

Comment: Where are you 'sending it to modal title'?

Comment: Also, returning a value from the emitted value's callback does nothing from what I understand.